# bash script is freezing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have several .pdb files that I need to process in order to retrieve readily available values from. I have made a bash script to try and mesh all the commands together.

My specific questions about this script are two:

1. My script is freezing after I try to run it in bash on the command line on Ubuntu by typing/entering ./myscript.bash and it is not outputting the desired files to the folder. What is the mistake in my script that could be causing this freeze up?
2. In the last commands,

   ```
   grep 'model*' $file >> $file"-confscore".txt
   #command to keep only the 1-5 lines from each dir I want to keep that contain this full format " model1   -5.00    0.21+-0.05  19.9+-1.8      404      0.003 " then >> combinedcscore.txt
   #Then reformat it to just "$dir model1 -5.00" >> newcombcscore.txt
   ```

   I don't know how to write this command in bash. The grep you see in the beginning will print the line containing any model* text to the file called $file___.txt. I need this in a specific format, which I included in the #'d lines underneath grep. I am thinking of using:

   ```
   for files in $dirs; do
   awk -F':' ' { print $dir model* firstvalueidk? }' >> newcombcscore.txt
   ```

   Is my use of awk correct?

Here's the full script for reference:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#Step 0 - Set up variables & navigate to app. directory
set GETLOCATION = "~/Desktop/DCompartment/RolandoHT_Scripts/Perl_Scripts"
set GETNAME = "get_right_pdb_format.pl"
set SSLOCATION = "~/Desktop/DCompartment/RolandoHT_Scripts/Perl_Scripts"
set SSNAME = "get_ss_dssp_itasser.pl"
set PROTALOCATION = "~/Desktop/protAlign-master/"
set dirs = ~/Videos/Proteins/*


#Step 1 - Process PDB for readily available values

for dir in $dirs; do
rm `cscore|model*.pdb|seq.fasta`
done

for dir in $dirs; do   
for file  in *.pdb; do
perl $GETLOCATION/$GETNAME $file
dssp -i $file"-fix" -o $file.dssp
perl $SSLOCATION/$SSNAME $file.dssp $file"-out"
done

for file in $dirs/*.dssp; do
grep 'ACCESSIBLE SURFACE OF PROTEIN' $file >> $file"-SASA".txt
done

for file in $dirs/*.txt; do
echo "$file `cat $file`" >> $dir-combinedSASAs.txt
done
done
#Step 2 - Set up tool
for dir in $dirs; do
./$PROTALOCATION/initialize.sh
source $PROTALOCATION/bin/activate
done
#Step 3 - Start analyzing files
for dir in $dirs; do
for file in *.pdb; do
./$PROTALOCATION/program_name.py $dir $dir/native.pdb $dir-SPAR  
done
done
for file in $dirs/data; do
set filerep = native-*.txt
grep 'TM-score' $filerep >> combinedreports.txt
awk 'FNR%2' combinedreports.txt > newcombinedrep.txt
done

for dir in $dirs; do
for file in cscore; do
grep 'model*' $file >> $file"-confscore".txt
#command to keep only the 1-5 lines from each dir I want to keep that contain this full format " model1   -5.00    0.21+-0.05  19.9+-1.8      404      0.003 " then >> combinedcscore.txt
#Then reformat it to just "$dir model1 -5.00" >> newcombcscore.txt    
done
done
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `set` in bash doesn't work as `set` in (t)csh.

Comment: Worth checking your script using [\[ shellcheck \]](http://shellcheck.net). Also `for file in cscore` may not be what you wanted to do.

Comment: Backticks are not single quotes so `rm \`cscore|model*.pdb|seq.fasta\`` is almost certainly not what you meant there.

Comment: Do you realise what `grep 'model*'` is searching for?  "mode" followed by zero or more "l"s.  The `*` in regular expressions is not the same as the `*` in filename expansion (globbing).

Comment: A simple test to see if your script is indeed blocked waiting on `stdin`, as the answer below suggests, is to hit `^Z` on the terminal to pause it, then type `bg` to run it in the background. If it immediately says `stopped`, or `jobs` says the same thing, the chances are it wants input. Then perhaps run `fg` and `^D` to close `stdin`, and see what happens... You might get an error from the exact command waiting for input.

Answer (score 1):

I think your script is freezing because all your variables are empty and commands like `grep` are blocking on STDIN!  I quickly cleaned up your script and added some code (prefixed with "GLR" comments) that I think you probably need.  Study this and it should get you a lot closer.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Step 0 - Set up variables & navigate to app. directory
GETLOCATION=~/Desktop/DCompartment/RolandoHT_Scripts/Perl_Scripts
GETNAME=get_right_pdb_format.pl
SSLOCATION=~/Desktop/DCompartment/RolandoHT_Scripts/Perl_Scripts
SSNAME=get_ss_dssp_itasser.pl
PROTALOCATION=~/Desktop/protAlign-master
dirs=~/Videos/Proteins/*


# GLR: uncomment the next line for debugging
#set -x


#Step 1 - Process PDB for readily available values

for dir in $dirs; do
    # GLR: Assume you want to change directory here?
    pushd $dir

    rm `cscore|model*.pdb|seq.fasta`

    # GLR: back to original directory
    popd
done


for dir in $dirs; do
    # GLR: Assume you want to change directory here?
    pushd $dir

    for file in *.pdb; do
        perl $GETLOCATION/$GETNAME $file
        dssp -i ${file}-fix -o $file.dssp
        perl $SSLOCATION/$SSNAME $file.dssp ${file}-out
    done

    for file in $dirs/*.dssp; do
        grep 'ACCESSIBLE SURFACE OF PROTEIN' $file >> ${file}-SASA.txt
    done

    for file in $dirs/*.txt; do
        echo "$file `cat $file`" >> $dir-combinedSASAs.txt
    done

    # GLR: back to original directory
    popd
done


#Step 2 - Set up tool
for dir in $dirs; do
    # GLR: Assume you want to change directory here?
    pushd $dir

    ./$PROTALOCATION/initialize.sh
    .  $PROTALOCATION/bin/activate

    # GLR: back to original directory
    popd
done


#Step 3 - Start analyzing files
for dir in $dirs; do
    # GLR: Assume you want to change directory here?
    pushd $dir

    for file in *.pdb; do
        ./$PROTALOCATION/program_name.py $dir $dir/native.pdb $dir-SPAR  
    done

    # GLR: back to original directory
    popd
done

# GLR: this won't do what you want
#for file in $dirs/data; do

for dir in $dirs; do
    # GLR: Assume you want to change directory here?
    pushd $dir/data

    #;filerep=native-*.txt
    #;grep 'TM-score' $filerep >> combinedreports.txt

    grep 'TM-score' native-*.txt    >> combinedreports.txt
    awk 'FNR%2' combinedreports.txt  > newcombinedrep.txt

    # GLR: back to original directory
    popd
done

for dir in $dirs; do
    # GLR: Assume you want to change directory here?
    pushd $dir

    for file in cscore; do
        grep 'model*' $file >> ${file}-confscore.txt

        # command to keep only the 1-5 lines from each dir I want to keep
        # that contain this full format
        #   " model1   -5.00    0.21+-0.05  19.9+-1.8      404      0.003 "
        # then >> combinedcscore.txt

        # Then reformat it to just "$dir model1 -5.00" >> newcombcscore.txt    
    done

    # GLR: back to original directory
    popd
done


exit 0
```